# Can't set up stripe payment method

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I'm trying to finish the payment feature on my app, first time trying to do this following a tutorial by Bryan Dunn. I added a SITE_URL like he did but I don't know if I need that since I added a proxy on my package.json and using axios to make api calls, I can use axios instead in this case? And when I click on "Proceed to checkout" button the url doesn't work, I tried changing it to a form.control, it gets redirected to the url but the stripe prebuilt form and product not showing up either.

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.getRoutes, name="get-routes"),
    path('users/register/', views.registerUser, name="register"),
    path('users/login/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('products/', views.getProducts, name="get-products"),
    path('products/<str:pk>', views.getProduct, name="get-product"),
    path('user/profile/', views.getUserProfile, name="get-user-profile"),
    path('users/', views.getUsers, name="get-users"),
    path('search/', ProductFilter.as_view(), name="search-product"),
    path('create-checkout-session/', StripeCheckoutView.as_view()),
]
```

views:

```
class StripeCheckoutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                line_items=[
                    {
                        'currency': 'usd',
                        'price': 'price_1MAtSLJU3RVFqD4TnNYWOxPO',
                        'quantity': 1,
                    },
                ],
                payment_method_types=['card'],
                mode='payment',
                success_url=settings.SITE_URL +
                '/?success=true&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                cancel_url=settings.SITE_URL + '/' + '?canceled=true',
            )
            return redirect(checkout_session.url)
        except:
            return Response(
                {'error': 'Something went wrong when creating stripe checkout session'},
                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )
```

cartScreen.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Image,
  ListGroup,
  Button,
  Card,
  Form,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Message from "../Message";
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from "../../actions/CartActions";
import { API_URL } from "../../config/config";

function CartSreen({ match, location, history }) {
  const productId = match.params.id;
  const quantity = location.search ? Number(location.search.split("=")[1]) : 1;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cartItems } = cart;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, quantity));
    }
  }, [dispatch, productId, quantity]);

  const removeFromCartHandler = (id) => {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(id));
  };
  const checkoutHandler = () => {
    history.push("/api/stripe/create-checkout-session");
  };
  return (
    <Row>
      <Col md={8}>
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
          <Message variant="info">
            Your cart is empty <Link to="/">Go Back</Link>
          </Message>
        ) : (
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            {cartItems.map((item) => (
              <ListGroup.Item key={item.product}>
                <Row>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid rounded />
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={3}>
                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>${item.price}</Col>
                  <Col md={3}>
                    <Form.Control
                      as="select"
                      value={item.quantity}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        dispatch(
                          addToCart(item.product, Number(e.target.value))
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                        <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                          {x + 1}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </Form.Control>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={1}>
                    <Button
                      type="button"
                      variant="light"
                      onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(item.product)}
                    >
                      <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
          </ListGroup>
        )}
      </Col>
      <Col md={4}>
        <Card>
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>
                Subtotal (
                {cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity, 0)}) items
              </h2>
              $
              {cartItems
                .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.price, 0)
                .toFixed(2)}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
          <ListGroup.Item>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              className="btn-block"
              disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
              action={checkoutHandler}
            >
              Proceed to Checkout
            </Button>
          </ListGroup.Item>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}

export default CartSreen;
```

config.js:

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

export const API_URL = "http://localhost:8000";

export const useQuery = () => {
  const { search } = useLocation();

  return useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);
};
```

app.js:

```
<Container>
 <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
 <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} exact />
 <Route path="/register" component={RegisterScreen} exact />
 <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} exact />
 <Route path="/cart/:id?" component={CartScreen} exact />
</Container>
```

settings:

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-gr1@(e6&lq%k8&v+%^xqp0966d6)_!q7(*l+y%8d)rt(6s_*hq'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'app.apps.AppConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    "corsheaders",
    'django_filters',
]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    )
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
]


...

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=30),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    # 'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=5),
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'django101',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]

MEDIA_ROOT = 'static/images'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = "sk_test_51MAt6AJU3RVFqD4Tz8TCWE7PL3xNn5iYvKe7r9ZUKN6dIPOm2AcFgfbiHlU43H1tEgbMKG93o8KNduJr86UFWbzc00RmWxOLY2 "

SITE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000"

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your components inside a [Form](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/overview/) so that the form redirect can work properly.

Comment: All component from top to bottom? @qichuan

Comment: It says "Page not found (404)" @qichuan

Comment: Yes, put all components inside the <Form>, especially the submit button. This is the link that I posted earlier https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/overview/